# BeautifulSoup fails to parse html with `html5lib`

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

BeautifulSoup fails to parse a html page with option `html5lib`, but works normally with the option `html.parser`. According to the [docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser), `html5lib` should be more lenient than `html.parser`, so why I met messy codes when using it to parse a html page ?

Following is a small executable example.(After change the `html5lib` with `html.parser`, the Chinese output are normal.)

```
#_*_coding:utf-8_*_
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ss = requests.Session()
res = ss.get("http://tech.qq.com/a/20151225/050487.htm")
html = res.content.decode("GBK").encode("utf-8")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html5lib')
print str(soup)[0:800]  # where you can see if the html is parsed normally or not
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't recode your content. Leave handling the decoding to Beautifulsoup:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, 'html5lib')
```

If you are going to re-encode, you need to replace the `meta` header that's present in the source:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
```

or manually decode and pass in Unicode:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content.decode('gbk'), 'html5lib')
```